# jQuery Droppable Ignores Drops

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

when you mousedown the outlined word, a little context menu drops. drag over the choice you want then release. in the current config, it acts as if user made no choice. if i change the droppable from #del to #target, then it works but obviously you can't choose tht way.

```
$(function() {
    $('#word').mousedown(function(ev, ui) {
        $("#target").slideDown(100);
    });    
    $('#word').mouseup(function(ev, ui) {
        $("#target").slideUp(100);
    });    
    $('#word').draggable({
        axis: 'y',
        containment: 'parent',
        revert: true, revertDuration: 100,
        stop: function() {
            $("#target").slideUp(100);
        }
    });
    $('#del').droppable({
        activeClass: 'over',
        drop: function() {
            var vote = alert("Delete action goes here");
        }
    });
});​
```

take a look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/monsto/PF3ty/7/

What am i missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

figured it out...

Put simply, the `draggable` `stop` parameter impedes `droppable` `drop`. It works after removing the `stop` definition and putting those actions in the in the `drop` definition.